# TFS 2013 - Migrate Team Project Code and History to New Project using different Process Template

Tags: tfs

I've just performed a successful upgrade from TFS2010 to TFS2013 in a UAT environment. The drive for this was to make use of the SCRUM template. However all the projects migrated are using the Agile template which was the default at the time they were created in 2010. My research into this has lead me to believe that they cannot be changed in-situ. Instead it would seem I need to create a new project and then migrate the code history over? I'm getting stuck here about how to go about this.

Can this be confirmed? Ideally all I want to-do is change the template, I only care about the code check-in history in the current projects.

The other option I've found is to use the TFS Integration Tools. But I don't believe this supports TFS2013. It errors on install asking for Team Explorer 2010,2008.

Can anyone assist in where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to timB33 for pointing me in the right direction.

To solve this I modified the script found [here](http://nakedalm.com/upgrading-your-process-template-from-msf-for-agile-4-to-visual-studio-scrum-2-x/).

```
set pt=C:\Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013\
set tpc=http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
set tp=MyAgileTP
REM #1 Do Renames
witadmin renamewitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /n:"User Story" /new:"Product Backlog Item" /noprompt
witadmin renamewitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /n:"Issue" /new:"Impediment" /noprompt
REM #2 Apply new Template
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Bug.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\CodeReviewRequest.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\CodeReviewResponse.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\FeedbackRequest.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\FeedbackResponse.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Impediment.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\ProductBacklogItem.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\SharedStep.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Task.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\TestCase.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Feature.xml"
REM #3 Import Link Types just in case coming from 2008
witadmin importlinktype /collection:%tpc% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\LinkTypes\SharedStep.xml"
witadmin importlinktype /collection:%tpc% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\LinkTypes\TestedBy.xml"
REM #4 Import Categories
witadmin importcategories /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\categories.xml"
REM #5 Import ProcessConfig
witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:%tpc% /p:%tp% /f:"%pt%WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml"
```

I ran this (pointing it at the downloaded template see the first pt variable) and I was then able to use all the SCRUM process template functionality. I haven't fully tested this yet but it seems like a winner. As my other option was to migrate the version control to another Team project but the limitation here was I lost all my version control timestamp history. Just didn't feel like the way to go. Hope this helps others.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can update the templates in-situ via (a witadmin script or) the tfs powertools plugin, this will let you export a SCRUM work item's template and then import it to your existing project, thus overwriting its WIT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will that then give me all the scrum template features as if I had created a new project, or does it just update the work item fields?

Comment: the latter (work items only). I've just googled this as I was wondering which features would be different (categories and process configurations apparently), and this link should help you, See http://nakedalm.com/upgrading-to-visual-studio-scrum-3-0-process-template-in-tfs-2013/

Comment: Thanks for those links, I had done so much googling I must have missed those. I took the scripts on there and adjusted slightly as it was missing a few things and all seems to have worked so far. I might add an answer to this encase anyone else is interested.

Comment: I would up vote your answer but apparently I need reputation of 15 or greater. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the new project has set the migrated template as the default.

To change the default: In team explorer, click on settings -> Process Template Manager, and change the default template for that project in the box that opens.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The default template for 2013 is SCRUM. However the projects that have been upgrade from 2010 are using AGILE. Changing the default only changes what a new project would use if you happened to just click next to all prompts when making a new team project and doesn't sadly convert old team project during an upgrade

Answer (score 0):

TFS Integration Platform works with TFS 2013. The errors on install asking for Team Explorer 2010,2008 can be resolved by installing Visual Studio 2012. The error is because of the missing TFS library object model.